# Texto con forma de json base de datos PHP

Tags: php

Buenas noches amigos tengo una base de datos que contiene un campo tipo longtext donde graban un json como texto.

```
"[{"nom":"(13) Radio AM FM - $13500","can":"1","sub":13500},{"nom":"(14) Audifonos Gamer - $40500","can":"3","sub":121500}]"
```

Y necesito convertirlo a un array multidimensional pero no he logrado hacerlo con PHP, lo he intentado con str_split con explode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa la función `json_decode`:

```
$json = json_decode('[{"nom":"(13) Radio AM FM - $13500","can":"1","sub":13500},{"nom":"(14) Audifonos Gamer - $40500","can":"3","sub":121500}]');
echo print_r($json,true);
```

Y obtendrás:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nom] => (13) Radio AM FM - $13500
            [can] => 1
            [sub] => 13500
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nom] => (14) Audifonos Gamer - $40500
            [can] => 3
            [sub] => 121500
        )

)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias estaba atascado con esto